# SharePoint site is not working on Android webview

Tags: android, sharepoint-2013

I am making an Android app using SharePoint, but I facing some issues when I am opening a site on web browser. It working fine, but trying to link with Android `WebView` it's giving a unknown host, also I have configured a proxy.

Url is `http://SharePoint:2080/sitepages/hom.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this,
actually android emulator does not take the host config from the machine, for sharepoint site work we have to set the DNS for the that using -dns-server command from the command line

or

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80570/connecting-to-sharepoint-from-android